# Is curled quote valid xml for attribute value

Tags: xml, double-quotes, single-quotes

For example is the following line a valid xml

```
<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8” ?>
```

It would be very helpful if somebody also able to provide reference for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the reference, the XML specification is at https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/ and the relevant rule is

```
[10]    AttValue       ::=      
           '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"'
        |  "'" ([^<&'] | Reference)* "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. Valid double quotes are hex 0x22 (plain ascii) while your example provided hex 0x201c.

A proper XML editor should provide the right ones.

> Historically, support for curved quotes was a problem in information technology, primarily because the widely used ASCII character set did not include a representation for them.

[Curved quotes within and across applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Curved_quotes_within_and_across_applications)